# Can someone explain the interrupt procedure of an MCU when performing calculations inside it?

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts

Suppose I am reading in a value every 100 microseconds using the ADC of a MCU. I have set up the ADC interrupt as well and inside that ADC interrupt I perform some calculations.

So if the ADC is set to read in the next ADC value every 100 microseconds, the only logical thing that I can think of is that within that period it needs to perform the calculations as well, correct ?

What if the calculations take longer to finish ? Can someone explain the theory behind this?

Comment: Can you tell us more about the nature of the signal which you are reading?  What's the nature of the calculations?  What's the ultimate goal (for example: data acquisition, or real-time control, or whatever else) ?

Answer (score 4):

It is all very simple. If the stream of calculations depend entirely on the sequence of the A/D readings then **YES** the calculations must be completed within the allotted time slot between the availability of the A/D readings.

With that said if there are characteristics of the computations that make some iterations take longer than others (especially  when that longer time overlaps the next A/D reading) then you will have to study and determine your long term average computation. Once you know that you can plan for these once in a while longer calculations by having the A/D interrupt do no calculations and instead put the A/D value into a circular buffer. The mainline code can take care of the calculations using values it pulls from the circular buffer. Using this technique things can still get done Okay. Keep in mind that stuffing things into and taking them out of the circular buffer does incur some performance hit.

Answer (score 2):

If the calculations take longer to finish than the interrupt period, you will either lose data by ignoring some of the interrupts, or run into a stack overflow because the interrupt handler will be called again and again before it has a chance to complete.

Comment: Stack overflow cannot occur on certain (most? all?) MCUs because requests with the same priority level are processed sequentially, ie handler finishes and is called again immediately, yet not recursively, if an interrupt fired in the meantime.

Comment: @Tibo true. I guess, even if another interrupt occurs, ideally the previous interrupt flag wouldn't have been cleared before the end of interrupt (unless you do manually) in which case it's like no interrupt occurred and hence no nesting.

Comment: Have you faced stack overflow because of not servicing interrupts?? In which controller?